# sql query accept only dates of two months

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to create a table with a constraint where the date column should only accept any dates in the month of May or November. 
How should I write the constraint like?

Comment: It's better to implement the input validation either in UI, or BI layer. Rgds,

Comment: I am Management Studio, did not see anywhere this option.

Comment: This is data validation, not just input validation @Alex. It's perfectly fine to perform validation outside the database but _all_ constraints you want on your data should be enforced in the database. If you don't do this you don't have a constraint on your data (which may be fine).

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this: Using `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the column or a `TRIGGER`.

The `CHECK Constraint` could look like this:

```
create table tbl(
    date_col date 
    check( MONTH(date_col) = 5 OR MONTH(date_col) = 11)
)
```

You have not specified a particular database so treat this as a pseudo-code only.

Comment: Alter table Exam with check add constraint [date_ck_validity] check  (Month([date]) = 5 or Month([date]) = 11) ........... Is this correct?

Comment: Looks like! You can always try it :)

Comment: If the data type of the column is date-only, this answer makes sense. But if this is a date-time, then you should also **consider time zone**. A a date-time in Paris may represent early in the first of May while at the same simultaneous moment in Montréal it is still the last day of April. In most cases, the data type of the date-time column in the database is UTC, not Paris or Montréal per my example.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question.  If you're just trying to retrieve values in may and nov, you can do this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE MONTH(yourTimeStamp)=5 or MONTH(yourTimeStamp)=11
```

If you're trying to keep values from other months out of the DB, you should really do that in the software that interfaces with the DB.

I'm no sql guru, but in the rare circumstance where I'm trying to discourage foreign software from messing with a DB in any way other that what I'm allowing, I'll write stored proceedures that take care of the constraints and just publish those proceedures to the software providers.

Comment: Not a good answer. Constraining data input to a specific range of values is a legitimate job of the database. In contrast to this answer, see the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26943237/642706) by NP3.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you shouldn't use constraints to check data type.  In my experience, it's just usually more coherent to leave things like only accepting data from may and November to the application, even if just for documentation purposes.  How are you going to feel as an app programmer when you write something that works in may and fails in june?

Comment: Actually you did suggest that (2nd paragraph). Either the "May & November Only" issue is a business rule or not. If it is a rule, the safest route is to enforce such rules in the database as the surest protection. Your comment makes the point -- if the app programmer screws up and allows bad data to flow through to the database, the database is a second chance to get it right. I don't understand your mention of the app programmer's feelings -- I suppose the programmer should feel grateful that the database person saved their bacon when their own work failed to enforce a requirement.

Comment: May and November is a data type?

Comment: But seriously, why the hostility toward someone trying to offer an answer?

Comment: Not sure what you meant exactly, but yes creating a data type (a [`DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createdomain.html) in SQL) can be a good way to go, especially if this business rule applies to more than one column. A DOMAIN extends another data type, wraps around a `CONSTRAINT`, and can be used as the specified data type when defining a column. What hostility? No hostility intended; I simply disagreed with your answer. If I'm mis-interpreting, perhaps you could edit your answer to more fully explain your intention.

Answer (score 0):

I concluded from your comments that you are using Management studio which is a part of SQL Server.

It uses the `datepart()` function.
You can see more here [Datepart documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

So for case it would be:

```
create table tbl(
  date_col date 
  check(datepart(month, date_col) = 5 OR datepart(month, date_col) = 11)
);
```